# SSHFS MacOs Read Only Issue

Tags: macos, amazon-ec2, fuse, sshfs

I've mounted an EC2 instance to my Mac using SSHFS and FUSE. The command I'm using to mount is:

```
sshfs ec2-user@IP_ADDRESS:/ ~/ec2Server/
```

It works fine, and I get the FUSE drive and I can see all the files. However, it's read only. How can I give myself read and write permissions?

I've tried changing the permissions with chmod but no joy. Can't seem to find anything on the web.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I would presume this is a combination of the user you are logging in with and the folder you are sharing. To be able to write anywhere you need to escalate your permissions to route on connect. I could not find any documentation if this was possible with sshfs.

Comment: I just made sure the user has root permissions, and I'm still experiencing the same behaviour :/

Comment: what do you mean by making sure the user has root permission? The user in concern here is `ec2-user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by giving the ec2-user ownership of the folder I wanted to work in:

sudo chown ec2-user /workplace