# Cannot write on sshfs mounted folder

Tags: macos, sshfs

I've mounted a folder of a Google Cloud Platform virtual machine on my local machine using the command

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/google_compute_engine \
user@remote-machine:/remote-folder \
~/gcp-remote -o allow_other,default_permissions
```

On my local machine I can read the folder contents, but not write to it. I am on MacOS, version 11.3. I've also tried `-o default_permissions`, `-o allow_other`, and removing `-o allow_other,default_permissions` altogether.

I also made sure that on the remote machine, the user I login via SSH is owner of the mounted folder. (I checked this after reading [SSHFS MacOs Read Only Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654213/sshfs-macos-read-only-issue?rq=1))

I tried creating a file with TextEdit, Atom, and also tried to create a folder using Terminal. All attempts were unsuccessful because of missing permission.

**How can I mount the folder with write access?**

Answer (score 0):

Once I put the mounted folder into the home folder of the user I login via SSH, it worked.